# what is green threading?

Tags: ruby

What is green threading means in ruby on rails , what it actually do? 
 Is it a. " A design where fixed size pool of threads is shared around the program?"
       b. "when threads are emulated by virtual machine or interpreter?" or 
       c. " where program run accross the multiple CPU?"

**Please explain with right ans?**

Comment: I fixed your tags. This is obviously homework, and I don't see what it's got to do with actionscript.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads

Comment: ohk sorry as i am new dont know much , i thought its multithreading question so add as actionscript . thank you so much , you helped improving question

Comment: it's from an eLance test, this is his way of passing them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) are threads that are emulated by a virtual machine or a runtime library instead of the operating system.

Comment: Google brought me here. Now, I need to click in this link.

Comment: @Ismael I'm sorry. This is one of my very first StackOverflow.com answers. I have tried to improve it a bit. Feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Green threads, also known as lightweight threads or fibers, are a concurrency mechanism in programming languages that provide a way to achieve concurrent execution without relying on operating system-level threads. In Ruby, green threads are implemented using fibers.

Here's an overview of fibers in Ruby and how they relate to green threads:

1. **Fibers:**

   - A fiber is a lightweight, cooperative concurrency primitive in Ruby. It allows you to create multiple, independent execution contexts within a single Ruby thread.
2. **Cooperative Concurrency:**

   - Unlike traditional threads that are preemptively scheduled by the operating system, fibers use cooperative concurrency. This means a fiber explicitly yields control back to the main thread or another fiber, allowing for cooperative multitasking.
3. **Creation and Execution:**

   - Fibers are created using the `Fiber` class in Ruby. Once created, a fiber can be paused and resumed, allowing for non-blocking, asynchronous execution.

   ```rb
   fiber = Fiber.new do
     puts "Fiber started"
     Fiber.yield
     puts "Fiber resumed"
   end

   puts "Main thread"
   fiber.resume
   puts "Back in main thread"
   fiber.resume
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   Main thread
   Fiber started
   Back in main thread
   Fiber resumed
   ```
4. **Green Threads:**

   - In the context of Ruby, fibers are often referred to as green threads because they provide a way to achieve concurrency within a single OS-level thread. They are managed by the Ruby interpreter (MRI - Matz's Ruby Interpreter) without relying on native threads.
5. **Use Cases:**

   - Green threads are useful for scenarios where you want to achieve concurrency without the overhead of native threads. They are often used in I/O-bound tasks, event-driven programming, and scenarios where you need to efficiently manage a large number of concurrent tasks.
6. **Async Libraries:**

   - Some Ruby libraries and frameworks leverage fibers for asynchronous programming. For example, the `async` library allows developers to write asynchronous code using fibers.

   ```rb
   require 'async'

   Async do
     puts "Async code"
     Async.yield
     puts "Resumed"
   end
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   Async code
   Resumed
   ```

It's important to note that the use of green threads is specific to the Ruby interpreter. Other Ruby implementations, like JRuby or Rubinius, might use native threads instead. Additionally, the introduction of Guilds in Ruby 3.0 is an ongoing effort to provide concurrent execution while addressing some of the limitations of traditional green threads.

Answer (score -1):

**Green Thread:**
Green threads are threads that are managed by a runtime library or a virtual machine, rather than by the operating system. They are usually lightweight and portable, as they do not depend on the underlying hardware or platform. Native threads are threads that are created and scheduled by the operating system, and they can leverage the capabilities of the CPU and the kernel. They are usually faster and more efficient, but they may also incur more overhead and compatibility issues.

**Benefits**
Green threads have several advantages over native threads, including the ability to create and destroy more threads than native threads without consuming system resources. Additionally, green threads can switch between threads faster than native threads since they do not involve system calls or context switches. Furthermore, they can implement custom scheduling policies and priorities as they have full control over the thread management. Finally, green threads can run on platforms that do not support native threads, such as embedded systems or browsers.

**Drawbacks**
Green threads have some drawbacks when compared to native threads, such as their inability to take advantage of multicore processors, which limits their scalability and parallelism. Furthermore, green threads cannot interact with native libraries or system calls that block, requiring special wrappers or bridges to handle the blocking operations. Additionally, green threads may suffer from performance degradation or inconsistency due to the quality and implementation of the runtime library or the virtual machine.

You can check more here with example! https://medium.com/@adrianbooth/exploring-rubys-multi-threaded-weirdness-d5dc61883591